# a char coding problem with apache httpclient and servlet

Tags: servlets, character-encoding

hi i'm communicating between an http client post techniq and a servlet.
if i send english chars there is no problem but if i send in hebrew i get ????? instead of hebrew, and i use UTF-8.
here is the client's code

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/dropboxweb/Delete");
            try {

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                        3);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fullpath",full.toString()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filename",name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user",Config.getInstance().getUsername()));

                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

and this is the servlet

```
//response.setContentType("text/html;charset=windows-1255");
        //response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        final String full_path =  request.getParameter("fullpath");
```

i tried all the optinos in // none worked.
i'm using tomcat 7.
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this, (it helped me)
What can you recommend to just make everything work? (How to use UTF-8 everywhere)
http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q3

Answer (score 0):

In the client side, you need to ensure that the following strings are **valid**.

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fullpath", full.toString()));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filename", name));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", Config.getInstance().getUsername()));
```

Check them by

```
System.out.println("fullpath: " + full.toString());
System.out.println("filename: " + name);
System.out.println("user: " + Config.getInstance().getUsername());
```

---

In the server side, you need to ensure that the following line is called **before** you get *any* request parameter.

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

You also need to ensure that the retrieved values are treated as UTF-8 in the remnant of the process. E.g. when writing to file, or printing to stdout console, or inserting in DB, all of those jobs also needs to be instructed to use UTF-8.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, current [RFC 1521] grammar restricts parameter values (and hence filename) to US-ASCII.
You should URL encode the file name on the client and URL decode it on the server.

Comment: The HttpClient and Servlet API's already implicitly do the URL encoding. My best guess is that the `System.out.println()` target console simply isn't been configured to use UTF-8.